# How to create a regional heat map based on zip codes and frequency of occurrences?

Tags: r, plot, maps, heatmap

I have a list of zip codes (with their long/lat) where people have taken a survey in that region.  I’d like to create a heatmap by the region showing the frequency of that survey occurrence.  I have tried chloropleth, arilamstein method, and other options indicated in this site, all to no avail,  I appreciate your assistance please.
Here is an image done in Excel: [image: geographical heatmap of data in Excel]

```
structure(list(Zip = c(49509, 49301, 49315, 49321, 49321, 49330, 
49341, 49341, 49341, 49401, 49401, 49401, 49401, 49418, 49418, 
49503, 49503, 49503, 49503, 49503), latitude = c(42.897764, 42.973443, 
42.803705, 43.073608, 43.073608, 43.241536, 43.124135, 43.124135, 
43.124135, 42.975656, 42.975656, 42.975656, 42.975656, 42.877992, 
42.877992, 42.96212, 42.96212, 42.96212, 42.96212, 42.96212), 
    longitude = c(-85.693418, -85.476998, -85.742196, -85.681875, 
    -85.681875, -85.736679, -85.490928, -85.490928, -85.490928, 
    -85.939287, -85.939287, -85.939287, -85.939287, -85.767881, 
    -85.767881, -85.659394, -85.659394, -85.659394, -85.659394, 
    -85.659394), city = c("Wyoming", "Ada", "Byron Center", "Comstock Park", 
    "Comstock Park", "Kent City", "Rockford", "Rockford", "Rockford", 
    "Allendale/GVSU", "Allendale/GVSU", "Allendale/GVSU", "Allendale/GVSU", 
    "Grandville", "Grandville", "Downtown", "Downtown", "Downtown", 
    "Downtown", "Downtown")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to `table` the coordinates and use `heatmap` on it, it's already built-in in R.

```
dat[c('latitude', 'longitude')] |> table() |> 
  heatmap(Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, scale='none', margins=c(7, 5), col=cm.colors(256))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for displaying the heatmap results itself.  Is there a way to express it as regional (geographical) map to show where the zip codes are located with their intensities.  I was able to do this in excel, but R is the formal language for this task in which to accomplish it.

Comment: @Shawn Maybe you want to add example Excel figure as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75442780/edit) to your question.

Comment: I included an image as suggested. Thank you.